# WebdriverIO and JavaScriptfor accessibility identifiers

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io

If I have two text fields, **first name** and **last name**, and set an accessibility identifier for them; the fields are both assigned `"nameID"` in an array form of `[@name="nameID"])[1]` and `[@name="nameID"])[2].`

I have attempted doing

```
$('~nameID[1]);
```

and

```
$('~[@name="nameID"])[1]');
```

with no results. How would I access these identifiers by name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding your question:

**Let's say this is how your HTML snippet looks like:**

```
First Name <input type="text" name="textName">
Last Name <input type="text" name="textName">
```

Both the text fields above has the same value for the attribute `name`.

**This is how you can access them:**

```
let textFields = $$('[name="textName"]');

// Access the First Name
textFields[0]

// Access the Last Name
textFields[1]
```

Note:

- More about selectors along with Name Attribute can be found in
  WebdriverIO API [here](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html)
- The solution above is very basic and the HTML snippet would never be that simple and you will have many options to access them.
- If you have more than 2 forms in your page and has many `input type texts` then definitely the solution above will not be appropriate to use.